Add space above and below the text using css
I want to add space above and below the text.
I tried adding margin-top but it was covered by another element.
How can I do this using CSS?
If anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it. Thanks!
My div code is:
<div id="idTestXxx" style="float:left; margin-left:120px; color:red; font-weight: bold; display: block; width: 400px; margin-top:5px;">※Test display description</div>

Image explained here

You should include the surrounding lines of contextual HTML code as text, not an image.

Use the CSS padding property instead of margin. Padding adds space inside of an element, while margin adds space outside of an element.


<div id="idTestXxx" style="float:left; margin-left:120px; color:red; font-weight: bold; display: block; width: 400px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">※Test display description</div>




Thank you for your reply but I have tried padding-top or margin-top and both have the same problem: ※Test display description will be covered by other elements.

From the beginning, on the interface there is no ※Test display description line between the two inputs Position and Lastname, I used javascript to add the div of ※Test display description

Remove float:left; from the style.

After removing float:left;, no matter how much I change the value of padding-top and padding-bottom, there is no change. Thank you for your enthusiastic support, I will investigate further.
